# Linear regression with weighted data?

Tags: fitting

`LinearModelFit` doesn't seem to support `WeightedData` objects. Is there anything I can do *smarter* than repeating the data proportionally to the weights?

MWE: The following code,

```
data = WeightedData[{{1, 1}, {3, 2}, {2, 3}}, {1, 2, 3}];
LinearModelFit[data, x, x]
```

gives the following error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: You're right in that it's strange that `WeightedData` doesn't work here, but `LinearModelFit` has the `Weights` options that you can use to specify the weights. See: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Weights.html

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Woah! I couldn't imagine such an option existed. If you want to write that as an answer, I would be willing to accept it. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: "I couldn't imagine..." - that's why it's good to read the docs. ;)

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thank you. I really try to read what I need. But I'd never know that I need something I can't imagine to exist. In this case, I think the Weights option was counter-intuitive for someone familiar with WeightedData (or at least just for me, maybe I'm mistaken).

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the weights?  Specifically, are you considering a model where the variance increases with `x` such as $y=a+b x+x \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?  Or are the weights related to the measured precision of an observation?  I ask because you might consider different options depending on what defines the weights.

Comment: @JimB, in this case, weights are _expansion factors_ to account for the representativity of each individual in the sample

Comment: "expansion factors to account for the representativity of each individual in the sample" seems kinda vague and/or arbitrary.  Why can't that be included in an explicit model rather than showing up only as an option in a software function?  (I'm not suggesting that weights don't exist.  I'm just looking for a concrete definition.)

Comment: @JimB not sure if I follow you. I'm translating from Spanish. _Factor de expansión_ is what they call them in (Spanish-speaking) transportation modelling. I _think_ in statistics (in English) they are called _probability weights_ of observations.

Comment: @JimB something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)#Survey_weights), if not exactly that.

Comment: OK, I see.  Survey weights is what you have in mind which are well-defined in finite population sample survey methods.  Usually those are built into the estimators of means, proportions, and totals.  The following article (http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/STS226.pdf) by Andrew Gelman might be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in that it's strange that `WeightedData` doesn't work here, but `LinearModelFit` has the `Weights` options that you can use to specify the weights. This example is from the documentation of `LinearModelFit` (specifically the `Weights` section under *Options*):

```
LinearModelFit[Range[10]^2, x, x] // Normal
LinearModelFit[Range[10]^2, x, x, Weights -> 1/Range[10]] // Normal
```

> > Out[1]= -22. + 11. x
> >
> > Out[2]= -13.5039 + 9.45526 x

As a general tip for finding these kinds of options, it's always worthwhile to browse the *Options* section in the documentation of a function if you think some logical functionality of a function is missing. Many option symbols have their own documentation page as well. Furthermore, some functions have hidden options that aren't shown in the documentation. You can see all of them by simply typing:

```
Options[LinearModelFit]
```

> > {ConfidenceLevel -> 19/20, IncludeConstantBasis -> True, 
> >      LinearOffsetFunction -> None, NominalVariables -> None, 
> >      Tolerance -> Automatic, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> Automatic, 
> >      Weights -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> Automatic}

Comment: If one already has the `WeightedData[]` object, one can just use the `"InputData"` and `"Weights"` properties to extract what needs to be given to `LinearModelFit[]`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay True, of course. That's why it's strange that it doesn't just work out-of-the-box, though.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, and that's why I just thought it wasn't implemented yet in the version I work with (not the latest one, I even think I remember reading a while ago that weights weren't universally implemented), and gave up early. Thanks, that's a welcoming way of saying "read the docs". I realize I could have tried harder before asking, I was just misguided and lost hope too early this time. Sorry.